# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown column name 'mobile' in table account_metric_usage

Tags: java, ormlite

The column "mobile" does indeed exists in my table. I am running mySQL database version 5.8+

Here is my java code that throws the exception:

> Where query =
>   dao.queryBuilder().selectColumns("mobile").where().eq(ACCOUNT,
>   account).and().ge(DATE, startStamp).and().le(DATE, endStamp);

the selectColumns only takes strings or iterator

If i run the query below on my database. i get the desired results:

```
SELECT mobile FROM account_profile_metric_usage WHERE ((account = 'qa23-redis-smoke' AND date >= '2017-01-28' ) AND date <= '2017-02-27' )
```

If i run the query below it fails to return the results since mobile is in quotes. Which is not what i want.

```
SELECT 'mobile' FROM account_profile_metric_usage WHERE ((account = 'qa23-redis-smoke' AND date >= '2017-01-28' ) AND date <= '2017-02-27' )
```

I need to be able to run the first SQL query in ormLite. mobile is of type bigInt

Comment: Have you tried to use the column name in uppercase?

Comment: Did you try to query data without the `selectColumns`. According to the documentation, this sould be return all columns of the table. You should see what your problem with this column.